# How to disable ARC for a linked Framework in xCode?

Tags: xcode, macos, compiler-construction, shared-libraries, automatic-ref-counting

I am aware of the accepted *and useful* solution for [`How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project).  However, there does NOT seem to be an easy, or even obvious way to do the same for a linked Framework.

[image: linked framework omit ARC]

**How can you convert / compile a binary under ARC, while omitting a linked Framework, via `-fno-objc-arc`, or otherwise?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the framework has already been compiled so there is no need for such an option?

AFAIK arc means code to retain and release etc is added at compile time

Comment: However, if trying to convert a project, as shown, the linked frameworks are globbed onto the process, making a mess of things.

Comment: Sorry cant see the image as I'm on my phone ! Will take a look when on a real computer